# Is there a way to create an uninstaller that works on any machine?

Tags: windows, installation, exe

From my understanding of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936030/how-do-i-create-an-uninstall-file-for-my-windows-application), an uninstaller is dynamically created when you install a program.

So, if I moved it to another computer, it wouldn't work (even if the same program was installed)?

Is there a way to create an executable or script that would uninstall a program if it exists on a system, regardless of file locations?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to create an uninstaller that will work on any system? If you mean cross-platform compatibility, it's already discussed here: [Cross Platform Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557441/cross-platform-installer)

If you are talking about Windows, You can use almost any installer setup program which automatically creates the uninstall entry for you. For example, [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), [NullSoft](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), and a flock of others.

Comment: I'm interested in Windows only, and I don't want to create a program from scratch then make an installer for it (but thank you, those links will be helpful in the future.) I'll use an example:  Let's say I have two computers. I've installed Spotify on both. I'd like to have a program on a flash drive that will uninstall Spotify from computer A or B - without having to go to Add/Remove programs or find the uninstaller for Spotify on both computers.

Comment: You can just run the uninstall executable from a batch script if that's the case. If the application does not have a dedicated uninstall executable, then you can use `wmic` in cmd and use `product where name=”NameOfProductYouWantToUninstall” call uninstall`